# node.js callback in a for-loop

Tags: node.js, loops, for-loop, callback

im trying to read some data and put it into a multi-array. To open the different files i use a for-loop, because i need the results to be numbered in the correct order. My problem:

I cant save the data in one array. Once I call the function to read the data, I can only use the result inside the function borders. How can I make the whole array available outside this function? (Pretty sure I am messing up the callbacks).

In other words: I am trying to open multiple files and save the content in one array [[file1], [file2], ...].

Here is my code:

```
var einlesen = require ('./einlesen/einlesen.js');

var einzeln = function(arg, callback){   //this is the function I use to read the data (it works fine, I checked it separately)
    einlesen.einlesen(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2], function(err, output){  //this function opens a file, works on the content and returns an array containing the needed data
        if (err) { return cb1(err); }
        callback(output);
    });
}

var daten_einlesen = function (callback){

    var tabellenarray = []; //initiating the array in which the whole info should go
    var tabelleninfos = [   //this array contains the info which data should be read, you only need to know that there are 16 files to be read, the rest is not important
                            ['gvz', '<|>', '1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1'], 
                            ['GZV', ';', '1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1'], 
                            ['XPG', ';', '1,1,1,1,1'], 
                            ['ABF', ';', '1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1'], 
                            ['GUS', '<|>', '1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1'], 
                            ['XPA', '<|>', '1,1,1'], 
                            ['ALW', '<|>', '1,1,1'], 
                            ['TAL', '<|>', '1,1,1'], 
                            ['ALB', '<|>', '1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1'], 
                            ['ZLB', '<|>', '1,1,1'], 
                            ['XAW', '<|>', '1,1,1'], 
                            ['SWS', ';', '1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1'], 
                            ['PRO', '<|>', '1,1'], 
                            ['VBP', '<|>', '1,0,1'], 
                            ['ZVP', '<|>', '1,1,1'],
                            ['config', ';', '0,0,1']];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){  //this is the loop where i try to open the files one by one and input them into the "tabellenarray"
        einzeln(tabelleninfos[i], function(tabelle){
            tabellenarray[i] = tabelle; //data is saved to the array but I lose the info onto the next step of the loop, if i put the final callback (below) in here the loop doesnt work anymore (naturally)
        });
    }       
    callback(tabellenarray);
}

daten_einlesen(function(piep){ //calling the whole function
console.log(piep);
});
```

I am grateful for any advice.

Nils

Comment: Which array? and outside which function u have to access??

Comment: I think I can help you, but what is `einlesen.einlesen()`? What does it do? Also - what output are you looking for?

Comment: Lets see... the function "einlesen" opens a .csv file, does some work on the data and returns an array. This array should then be saved into a multi-array "tabellenarray", so in the end "tabellenarray" has an array for each argument with the data of the different files opened with "einlesen". Thats where i try to use the for loop, it calls the function "einlesen" for every item in "tabelleninfos" and is supposed to save the returned data into "tabellenarray". In the end of the whole function i want to return "tabellenarray" so I can work with all of the data.

Comment: I think that because einzeln executes asynchronously the data that you may be calling `callback(tabellenarray)` prematurely, this tends to be the problem with combining asynchronous code with side-effects. Pending flags or promises may help. I'll answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for starters:

```
var pending = 3,complete=0;
for (var i = 0; i < pending; i++){  //this is the loop where i try to open the files one by one    and input them into the "tabellenarray"
    einzeln(tabelleninfos[i], function(tabelle){
        tabellenarray[i] = tabelle; //data is saved to the array but I lose the info onto the next step of the loop, if i put the final callback (below) in here the loop doesnt work anymore (naturally)
        if(++complete >= pending){
            callback(tabellenarray);
        }
    });
}
```